# xrandr not showing hdmi and vga port, external monitor not dectected

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia, xrandr, hdmi, vga

I'm trying to plug an external hdmi monitor to my laptop, but it's not detected...

System: Ubuntu 14.04
Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-6820HQ CPU @ 2.70GHz × 8 
Graphics: Quadro M2000M/PCIe/SSE2

Output of `xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 2160, maximum 16384 x 16384
DP-0 disconnected primary (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-5 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
eDP1 connected 3840x2160+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 346mm x 194mm
   3840x2160      60.0*+
   2048x1536      60.0  
   1920x1440      60.0  
   1856x1392      60.0  
   1792x1344      60.0  
   1920x1200      60.0  
   1920x1080      59.9  
   1600x1200      60.0  
   1680x1050      60.0     59.9  
   1600x1024      60.2  
   1400x1050      60.0  
   1280x1024      60.0  
   1440x900       59.9  
   1280x960       60.0  
   1360x768       59.8     60.0  
   1152x864       60.0  
   1024x768       60.0  
   800x600        60.3     56.2  
   640x480        59.9  
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

Output of `sudo lshw -C display`:

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: GM107GLM [Quadro M2000M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:133 memory:c3000000-c3ffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff memory:c0000000-c1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:c4000000-c407ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 530
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915_bpo latency=0
       resources: irq:131 memory:c2000000-c2ffffff memory:60000000-6fffffff ioport:5000(size=64)
```

My `xorg.conf`:

```
Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier "layout"
    Screen 0 "nvidia"
    Inactive "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "intel"
    Driver "modesetting"
    BusID "PCI:0@0:2:0"
    Option "AccelMethod" "None"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "intel"
    Device "intel"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Driver "nvidia"
    BusID "PCI:1@0:0:0"
    Option "ConstrainCursor" "off"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier "nvidia"
    Device "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration" "on"
    Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
EndSection
```

Any help would be appreciated. 
Thanks!

Comment: It looks like your laptop screen is connected to one graphics card, while the HDMI output is connected to the other graphics card, and your xorg.conf fails to activate both graphics card in Xinerama mode (or whatever you want), so only one card is active. Please put `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` in a pastebin etc. and post a link, so we can see what is going on.

Comment: Hi @dirkt ,  the Xorg.0.log is here: [Xorg.0.log](http://pastebin.com/5kQ9Utyt)
Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, but observations: (1) It's not the newest X server version, so possibly upgrading to a newer version could help. (2) ServerLayout/Inactive doesn't seem to do anything (eDPI is connected to the Intel card, and it activates), and it only works for older X servers, anyway. Remove it and see if it makes any difference. (3) Can't see the HDMI output in the log. Please connect the HDMI monitor *before* poweron, then power on and boot with monitor connected, and post the log.